# How to fix unable to launch

Tags: xubuntu

I get the error when I try to start ubuntu

```
unable to launch "gnome--session --session=ubuntu" 
X session --- "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" not found; 
falling back to defualt session.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error because your desktop session has been messed up. You can recover by reinstalling.

Open virtual console by ctrl+alt+f1 and execute below it will work.

```
# sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
# sudo reboot
```

Comment: in recovery menu I can't move up and down its write read-only

Comment: @abo7mid `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: Why reboot? `sudo service lightdm restart`